# JWT token for multiple websites

Tags: authentication, cross-domain, jwt

How can I have a single JWT token be shared among multiple websites. I assume that the first thing would be to have the same secret on all websites.

If user logs in on site A and a token is generated I want to use the same token for website B on a totally diferent domain.

Can it be done?

Comment: I have the similar thought about using single JWT to implement single sign on. The problem is how to store the JWT for each application, before users send requests. Actually, it's easy to verify the idea via `curl` command, but harder to share the JWT in `localStorage` than `cookie`. Do you have some good news right now?

Answer (score 15):

What you want can be done, but not with a **single** JWT token. A JWT token is intended for a certain service or application indicated by the audience (`aud`) claim. You cannot use the same token for another application or service.

What typically happens to make your [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) scenario work, it that the user logs in to the token issuing (authorization) server. As long as that session is valid, the user can acquire tokens for all applications the server can issue tokens for.

So, when the user logs in to the first application, the authorization server sets a cookie to establish a session. When the user navigates to the second application, the application redirects him/her to the authorization server for authentication. The authorization detects the session cookie and does not prompt to user to log in again, but issues a new JWT token for the second application.

Comment: What about if I don't want to use cookies at all. I know that JWT tokens can be used stateless (without the need of the server to know about it). My thinking: when user logs in on the authorization server, the server should generate all tokens needed for all applications and when the user access app B it will already have the token stored. Does this makes any sense?

Comment: Obviously if you own the authorization server, you can do whatever you want. But even if the authorization server uses cookies to support a session, that does not mean your web API has to. The important thing is that the authorization server somehow is able to authenticate the user without prompting him for credentials.

Comment: What do you mean by "session cookie"? What would this contain and how would you generate this? Would it basically be the JWT?

Comment: I have similar question as described in @Cristian comment , if client disables cookie, how does the authorization server issue a new JWT for resource server (the 2nd. application) ? by putting the signed JWT to response body of the request then save it to memory (e.g. Javascript variable) in client's browser ? or any alternative that is more appropriate on that matter ?