# How to redirect asp .net core API to external URL from angular SPA client

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, single-page-application, external-url

Basically I am new to SSO. I have two websites [www.angularwebsite.com](http://www.angularwebsite.com) which talks to a .net core web API.Using azure ad , I can authenticate myself and I am able to log into [www.angularwebsite.com](http://www.angularwebsite.com) using an Authorisation header "Bearer ". So far this is working.
We have another website [www.ecommercesite.com](http://www.ecommercesite.com) which is using SAML to authenticate Azure and it also works fine. Now how do I call this [www.ecommercesite.com](http://www.ecommercesite.com) from my [www.angularwebsite.com](http://www.angularwebsite.com) after authentication so that the tokens which I got by authenticating on [www.angularwebsite.com](http://www.angularwebsite.com) is valid.
Basically I don''t know how/where to call the [www.ecommercesite.com](http://www.ecommercesite.com) (in angular by window.location.href) or in .NET API core
My startup.cs in API CORE's classes are as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc();
            //How do redirect when I come from angular to www.ecommercesite.com
        }
```

My snippet of ConfigureService is as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, configureOptions: null);

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy =
                 new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
        });
```

All the references to where I looked point to SSO with SPA and .Net core aPI which I already got. I am not able to find **"what if I want to navigate to another website"**using the same token. Kindly direct me to right place, I can try it myself. I don't know how to do.Thank you
Regards,
Jaga

Comment: Maybe it is too late in your development cycle, but I advise spending some time reading about  IDPs that use OpenId Connect (There is too much to explain in one comment), There are a number of libraries that make handling this very very easy and as far as I know it is the standard for authentication and Authorization at the moment. I personally use IdentityServer4

Comment: Thanks Kevin. As I said the authentication against Azure AD between Angular and .Net core WebAPI is working with the Azure ID token. What I want is How do I then use the same token to call another website which is also authenticated using the same method. Where do the call for the external website go? Is it in the .net Core API where the token will be available? How do I do it there.

Comment: The intent of the IDP isn't to solve authentication, you can integrate any 3rd party authentication easily Google, AD, Facebook etc and federate them together if you so wish. It makes it easy to verify your clients and what API's a client is allowed to access. I really think you need to consider your security design.

Comment: this answer explains what you will need to do. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35438142/5517088