# how to use one jwt token from One Api for Authentication all Apis in local enterprise application asp.net core (not use idedentityserver)

Tags: asp.net-core

I need run Api Authentication server(use jwt) for all apis in local application .how to create it with out use identityserver ?
How can the initial token be validated on other Apis?
How to send the received token to the first server for validation and received the answer initial this token to this server ?

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the following steps to use JWT Authentication In ASP.NET Core.

1. Configure the authentication schema with JWT bearer options.

   ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .AddJwtBearer(options =>
               {
                   options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {
                       ValidateIssuer = true,
                       ValidateAudience = true,
                       ValidateLifetime = true,
                       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                       ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                       ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                   };
               });
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

   }
   ```
2. In this example, I have stored these values in appsettings.json file.

   ```
    {
        "Jwt": {
          "Key": "ThisismySecretKey",
          "Issuer": "Test.com"
        }
    }
   ```
3. Call the app.UseAuthentication() method in the Configure method of startup class.

   ```
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
   ```
4. Generate JSON Web Token

   ```
    using System; 
    using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt; 
    using System.Security.Claims;
    using System.Text; 
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization; 
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
    using Test.Models;

    namespace Test.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class LoginController : ControllerBase
        {
            private IConfiguration _config;

            public LoginController(IConfiguration config)
            {
                _config = config;
            }
            [AllowAnonymous]
            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Login([FromBody] UserModel login)
            {
                IActionResult response = Unauthorized();
                var user = AuthenticateUser(login);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    var tokenString = GenerateJSONWebToken(user);
                    response = Ok(new { token = tokenString });
                }

                return response;
            }

            private string GenerateJSONWebToken(UserModel userInfo)
            {
                var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
                var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userInfo.Username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, userInfo.EmailAddress),
                new Claim("DateOfJoing", userInfo.DateOfJoing.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    claims,
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
                    signingCredentials: credentials);

                return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            }

            private UserModel AuthenticateUser(UserModel login)
            {
                UserModel user = null;

                //Validate the User Credentials    
                //Demo Purpose, I have Passed HardCoded User Information    
                if (login.Username == "Jignesh")
                {
                    user = new UserModel { Username = "Jignesh Trivedi", EmailAddress = "test.btest@gmail.com" };
                }
                return user;
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Then, if you request the "API/login" method to generate the token, you have to passed the following JSON in the request body.

```
{"username": "Jignesh", "password": "password"}
```

Then, after getting the JWT token, you could add the "Authorization" property in the request header when you access other API controller.

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJKaWduZXNoIFRyaXZlZGkiLCJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3QuYnRlc3RAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiRGF0ZU9mSm9pbmciOiIwMDAxLTAxLTAxIiwianRpIjoiYzJkNTZjNzQtZTc3Yy00ZmUxLTgyYzAtMzlhYjhmNzFmYzUzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTMyMzU2NjY5LCJpc3MiOiJUZXN0LmNvbSIsImF1ZCI6IlRlc3QuY29tIn0.8hwQ3H9V8mdNYrFZSjbCpWSyR1CNyDYHcGf6GqqCGnY
```

If you mean using one JWT token for multiple API applications, as far as I know, a JWT token is intended for a certain service or application indicated by the audience (aud) claim. You cannot use the same token for another application or service.

More detail information please check the following links:

[JWT Authentication In ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/)

[JWT token for multiple websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423800/jwt-token-for-multiple-websites)

Comment: thanks .I want something like identityserver .I need a custom sso with asp.net core for app.